# Horizontal Linear Layout - last view is slided outwards

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I use a custom base dialg layout with an action bar... I have a bottom bar with buttons on the bottom. If the last button has two lines, the complete `TextView` slides outside of it's parent `LinearLayout`... Why is this happening?

**Screenshot**

I pressed the last button to show the problem... The last button is slided downwards... The screenshot shows the `llButtonBar` from the layout...

[image]

**PROBLEM**

[image]

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/vDividerButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNegative"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vVerticalDivider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNeutral"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vVerticalDivider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btPositive"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Eh, so what is the question? Do you want the lalel to centre-aligned?

Comment: I added a second screenshot... hopefully it's more clear now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below property to (llButtonBar) bottom Linearlayout :

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: It's a dialog... The content may be a single line textview or something more complex... Using a ratio between content and bottom bar is not working for this scenario...

Comment: actually, that works... I should have thought about that, after CKD Publishing postet his suggestion...

Comment: I still don't understand, why the right button slides to bottom and not the llButtonBar get's bigger and the buttons on the left are aligned on top....

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `layout_gravity` to the `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `android:gravity="center_vertical"`. Typo mistake.

Comment: @prom85: No worries. Glad we could help you resolve the problem.